# Following up an emailed application

Tags: job-search, applications, email

I saw a job advertised with a 'closing date for applications of 31st July'

Sent my CV and covering letter as prescribed by the website to the email address specified

I did not receive an automated acknowledgment or any response (I checked and double checked the email address I sent it to was correct)

How long is it polite to wait until following up? And if so, obviously I would need to follow up via email, so not quite sure how to phrase the follow up

I'm not sure this is a duplicate of [What do I say when following up a job application that I haven't heard back from?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/23418/what-do-i-say-when-following-up-a-job-application-that-i-havent-heard-back-from) but if so, happy to remove my post

Comment: Shoot, not the one I meant to select. Yes, I think it is a duplicate of the one you posted and should be closed.

Answer (score -1):

Just assume that  you not successful  and move on. But would you want to work for a company that does not answer correspondence?

Comment: as far as I know email protocol doesn't guarantee delivery. Because of that, assuming that it means company does not answer correspondence sounds a bit... premature. (I also recall in one of past projects our team had a lot of mails lost due to simple technical mistake - misconfiguration of spam filter)

Comment: They was not lost. They was identified as spam.

Comment: For all intense and purposes it has delivered. Why waste time?

Comment: Besides you get an email that it could not be delivered

Comment: at our side it looked like these were lost (it is only natural that spam filter doesn't send delivery failure notification to suspected spammers). Anyway, my point is, delivery can occasionally fail / delay for many various reasons. If asker had evidence that this is a recurring issue, it could at least somehow indicate troublesome company. But as it happened only once, one can't  really tell

Comment: @gnat - hitting a spam filter means it has been delivered. Just like any other mail. Does not mean it is read. But the point is why waste more effort. More fish in the sea